# I need to prevent overlay from closing on click

Tags: javascript

Hi guys I have a form on an overlay put the problem is when they use the form the overlay closes is there any way to prevent this? Thanks, I appreciate it.

```
   #JS
  reserveBttn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  resPopup1(element);
  document.querySelector('.close- 
  respopup').addEventListener('click', () => {
    window.location.reload();
  });
});

# More JS 
export const pop = document.querySelector('.respopup');
const reservation = [];
const resPopup1 = ({ show }) => {
const resPopupBg = document.createElement('div');
resPopupBg.classList.add('respop');
 resPopupBg.style.backgroundImage = `url(${show.image})`;
 pop.appendChild(resPopupBg);

const resContainer = document.createElement('section');
resContainer.classList.add('rescontainer');
resPopupBg.appendChild(resContainer);

 
const respopupInfo = document.createElement('div');
respopupInfo.classList.add('popup-info');
resContainer.appendChild(respopupInfo);

 const respopupTitleContainer = document.createElement('div');
 respopupTitleContainer.classList.add('popup-title-wrap');
 respopupInfo.appendChild(respopupTitleContainer);

 const respopupTitle = document.createElement('h2');
 respopupTitle.classList.add('tittle-popup');
 respopupTitle.innerHTML = show.name;
 respopupTitleContainer.appendChild(respopupTitle);

 const resCloseImg = document.createElement('img');
 resCloseImg.classList.add('.close-respopup');
 resCloseImg.setAttribute('src', './img/icon-close-white.svg');
 respopupTitleContainer.appendChild(resCloseImg);

 
 const reservationForm = document.createElement('form');
 reservationForm.classList.add('reservation-form');
 reservationForm.setAttribute('action', '');

 const reservationFormTitle = document.createElement('h2');
 reservationFormTitle.classList.add('reservation-form-title');
 reservationFormTitle.textContent = 'Add a reservation';

  const reservationFormName = document.createElement('input');
  reservationFormName.classList.add('reservation-form-name');
    reservationFormName.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  reservationFormName.setAttribute('name', 'FullName');
  reservationFormName.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Full Name')
 
  const resBtn = document.createElement('BUTTON');
  resBtn.innerHTML = 'Reserve';
  resBtn.classList.add('res-btn');
  reservationForm.appendChild(resBtn);
  reservationForm.appendChild(reservationFormTitle);
  reservationForm.appendChild(reservationFormName);
  reservationForm.appendChild(reservationFormDate);
  reservationForm.appendChild(reservationFormTime);

  respopupInfo.appendChild(reservationForm);
  };

  export default resPopup1;
```

So I not sure what in the code is making the overlay close when I use the form but if anyone has any advise I would love to hear it.

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Comment: Impossible for us to guess what is closing it. So is there more code? More event listeners? Is it a library?

Comment: ok I will add more code thanks guys

Comment: Just like `reserveBttn` there will an event handler for overlay, can you post that code.

Answer (score 0):

#### Updated Answer after more code provided

There are some things that could be happening. The first idea is: Your `window.location.reload()` is being called inside the click callback. Try just removing that and it could work.

Another possible thing is: On forms if you don't specify the `type` attribute from a `<button>`, it'll default to `type="submit"`, which will submit the form if clicked. Adding the `event.preventDefault()`/`event.stopPropagation()` to the callback could work or just add the `type="button"` to your `<button>` element:

```html
<form>
  <button type="button">This button does not submit the form</button>
  <button type="submit">This button submit</button>
</form>
```

Hope something helps you!

#### Original Answer

You could access the `event` argument that is passed to the callback `addEventListener('myEvent', (event) => {})` and call the `event.preventDefault()` or even the `event.stopPropagation()`. It'll be something like this:

```js
document.querySelector('.close-respopup').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  window.location.reload();
});
```

Comment: um, it is reloading the page, preventing it will do what? ;)

Comment: Based on what I understood, what the OP wants is to prevent the overlay from closing and not the page from reloading. But that was what I understood and I could be wrong.

Comment: @IlêCaian exactly I want the overlay to stay open when they add data into the form and thanks for the advise